# Joining tables by skipping the intermediate parent table

Tags: sql, mysql, join

We've tables `adm_app`, `quals_data` to which `personal_data` is a parent table. We are retrieving data from another table `sub_marks` which has a foreign key of `quals_data` and the query is like this

```
select
      sub_marks.obtain_marks,
      sub_marks.convertion_marks,
      sub_marks.max_marks
from sub_marks
inner join quals_data ON quals_data.id = sub_marks.quals_data_id
inner join adm_app on quals_data.personal_data_id = adm_app.personal_data_id
where adm_app.app_no = 2000;
```

You can see that we've skipped the join with `personal_data` because we are not using its data anywhere. Is this a good way of writing a query? Previously we wrote query like this

> ```
> select
>       sub_marks.obtain_marks,
>       sub_marks.convertion_marks,
>       sub_marks.max_marks
> from sub_marks
> inner join quals_data ON quals_data.id = sub_marks.quals_data_id
> inner join personal_data ON personal_data.id = quals_data.personal_data_id
> inner join adm_app on adm_app.personal_data_id = personal_data.id
> where adm_app.app_no = 2000;
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your changes to the query are good changes.

Just because the both `adm_app` and `quals_data` have the same child relationship to the `personal_data` table does not mean you have to include the `personal_data` table in a join if there's no relevant data on it.

You should run both of your queries with the query-plan [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) to show the difference in the queries. Avoiding the join will make for a simpler query with better performance.

Having said that, what about the rest of your query, are there improvements that can be made? Nothing big, really. I am not a big fan of `snake_case` for table and column names, but it is more important that you are consistent, and neat with the concept.

If I were to have any complaints, it would just be two really small things:

- a spelling error.... I know, it's seriously pedantic, but in my "real job" I would point out the error soon because it is the sort of thing that is hard to correct later... `convertion` should be spelled `conversion`
- abbreviations should be consistent in names. Since you have `personal_data` and fully named columns like `convertion_marks`, then it follows that you should not have abbreviations for `adm_app` and `quals_data`. Those should be full names.

As you can tell, the only issues I can see are really trivial.

Comment: Good points, its a new thing for a guy like me